# Meaning of CF_OPEN_FILE_FLAG_FOREGROUND flag with CfOpenFileWithOplock

Tags: file-locking, cloud-files-api

The flag `CF_OPEN_FILE_FLAG_FOREGROUND` is not documented in either the documentation for [CF_OPEN_FILE_FLAGS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/ne-cfapi-cf_open_file_flags) nor in the documentation for [CfOpenFileWithOplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfopenfilewithoplock).

What is this flag's meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following information was supplied via a Microsoft Case:

> `CF_OPEN_FILE_FLAG_FOREGROUND` is not documented, probably it was added
> at a later stage.
>
> Based on the code, it seems that If a caller doesn’t want to use
> Oplocks, they should use this flag when calling `CfOpenFileWithOplock`.
> It implies that `FILE_OPEN_REQUIRING_OPLOCK` wouldn’t be set when the
> API calls `CreateFile()` underneath.
>
> By default, the `FOREGROUND` flag is not specified, so the default
> behavior of `CfOpenFileWithOplock` is to request an oplock. That would
> make it consistent with defaulting to background behavior.
>
> In this context “foreground” seems to mean that the caller is acting
> as a foreground application. I.e., they don’t care whether the file
> handle created by this API causes sharing violations for other
> callers, and they don’t care about breaking any oplocks that may
> already be on the file, so they open the handle without requesting an
> oplock.   The default “background” behavior requests an oplock when
> opening the file handle so that their call fails if there’s already an
> oplock, and they can be told to close their handle if they need to get
> out of the way to avoid causing a sharing violation later.
>
> Side note: unless the caller specifies `CF_OPEN_FILE_FLAG_EXCLUSIVE` to
> `CfOpenFileWithOplock`, the oplock they get will be only
> `OPLOCK_LEVEL_CACHE_READ`, not (`OPLOCK_LEVEL_CACHE_READ | OPLOCK_LEVEL_CACHE_HANDLE`), so there won’t be the sharing violation
> protection a background app might normally want.

Note: Microsoft has (since this case) has now documented this flag.

Further information was provided in this case, and is shared here as it is relevant in general to this API:

> A background application typically wants to operate transparently on
> files. In particular, they want to avoid causing sharing violations to
> other (foreground) openers. To do that, they take a `CACHE_READ | CACHE_HANDLE` oplock, such as would be granted by using
> `CF_OPEN_FILE_FLAG_EXCLUSIVE` with `CfOpenFileWithOplock`. Then, if some
> other opener comes along whose requested share/access modes conflict
> with the background app’s, the background app’s oplock breaks. This
> prompts the background app to close their file handle (for a `Cf`
> handle, that causes it to become invalid – the real underlying handle
> has been closed). Once the background app closes their handle, the
> other opener’s open proceeds without hitting the sharing violation.
> That all works because of the `CACHE_HANDLE` part of the oplock. Without
> `CF_OPEN_FILE_FLAG_EXCLUSIVE`, the oplock only has `CACHE_READ`
> protection, so that sharing violation protection I described doesn’t
> happen.

---

> 1. If `CF_OPEN_FILE_FLAG_EXCLUSIVE` is specified, the open is “share none” and it gets a `CACHE_READ | CACHE_HANDLE` oplock.
>    a.    A normal
>    `CreateFile` call that opens for any of `FILE_EXECUTE | FILE_READ_DATA | FILE_WRITE_DATA | FILE_APPEND_DATA | DELETE` (or either/both of
>    `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE`) will break the oplock due to the sharing
>    conflict, as described above. **The oplock owner will get to finish and
>    acknowledge.**
> 2. If `CF_OPEN_FILE_FLAG_EXCLUSIVE` is not specified, the open is “share all” and it gets a `CACHE_READ` oplock.
>
>    a. A normal `CreateFile` call
>    will not break the oplock.
>
>    b. If the normal `CreateFile` specifies a
>    sharing mode that conflicts with the `Cf` handle’s access (for instance,
>    if the normal `CreateFile` does not specify `FILE_SHARE_READ`), the normal
>    `CreateFile` will fail with `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`.
>
>    c. The oplock doesn’t break until the other caller issues a conflicting I/O, such as a write. When that happens the **oplock break is advisory only**.

---

> The way the Cf APIs use oplocks, the “exclusive” oplock is the only one that breaks the way you’re expecting.

(i.e. a break that is not just advisory)